# ID Filtering based on single date field with no end date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, window-functions

Table *Category*

```
+----+--------+----------+------------+
| ID | Active | Category | Effective  |
+----+--------+----------+------------+
|  1 | FALSE  | A        | 1/29/2009  |
|  1 | FALSE  | B        | 5/13/2014  |
|  1 | TRUE   | B        | 9/21/2017  |
|  2 | FALSE  | B        | 3/4/2010   |
|  2 | TRUE   | A        | 2/19/2016  |
|  3 | FALSE  | A        | 10/15/2015 |
|  3 | TRUE   | B        | 8/12/2017  |
+----+--------+----------+------------+
```

Table *Runtime*

```
+----+------------+
| ID |  RunDate   |
+----+------------+
|  1 | 6/14/2015  |
|  1 | 9/14/2015  |
|  1 | 10/4/2016  |
|  2 | 5/1/2014   |
|  2 | 9/21/2016  |
|  3 | 3/12/2016  |
|  3 | 12/14/2017 |
+----+------------+
```

I'm trying to select only those `ID`s that had a rundate while `Category` A was effective point-in-time. So `ID` 1 shouldn't be in the output because even though it had Category A, its rundate was after Category B took effect.

Expected Output

```
+----+
| ID |
+----+
|  2 |
|  3 |
+----+
```

Attempt:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    RT.ID
FROM Category C
INNER JOIN Runtime RT
    ON C.ID=RT.ID
WHERE 1=1
    AND C.Category='A'
    AND RT.rundate >= C.effective
ORDER BY RT.ID
```

This however, does not consider the intermediate changes and simply selects results based on if any of the effective dates per ID were before the rundate

Comment: In short, it seems like either you want to use a cross apply on the category table (e.g. `cross apply (select top 1 c2.effective from category as c2 where c2.id = c.id and c2.effective > c.effective and c2.category != 'a' order by c2.effective) as c2`) then do an additional clause (`where rt.rundate <= c2.effective`) or something like that. The same effective could be achieved with a self join instead of a cross apply, though you'd have to apply something like a `row_number()` window function and select only the first results.

Comment: You could also use a `LEAD()` window function (because even if the next row were also an 'A', it wouldn't make much difference). e.g. `select distinct rt.id from (select *, nextEffective = lead(effective) over (partition by id order by effective) from category) as c... and rt.rundate >= c.effective and (c.nextEffective is null or rt.rundate <= c.nextEffective)...`

Answer (score 0):

-- Please try this Query

```
;with cte_category(Id, Effective,Rundate)
AS
(
SELECT c.id, max(c.effective)effective, max(r.rundate)rundate
FROM Category c
INNER JOIN runtime r on r.id = c.id
WHERE r.rundate>c.effective
GROUP BY c.id
)
SELECT DISTINCT t1.id
FROM cte_category t1
INNER JOIN cte_category t2 
    ON t1.id > t2.Id
    AND t2.Effective < t1.Rundate
ORDER BY t1.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample data preparation

```
declare @category table ( ID int, Active varchar(10), Category char(1), Effective date)
insert into @category
values (1, 'FALSE', 'A', '20090129')
    , (1, 'FALSE', 'B', '20140513'), (1, 'TRUE ', 'B', '20170921')
    , (2, 'FALSE', 'B', '20100304'), (2, 'TRUE ', 'A', '20160219')
    , (3, 'FALSE', 'A', '20151015'), (3, 'TRUE ', 'B', '20170812')

    , (4, 'FALSE', 'B', '20151015'), (4, 'FALSE ', 'A', '20170812')
    , (4, 'True ', 'A', '20180812')
    , (3, 'TRUE ', 'A', '20270812')

declare @runtime table (ID int, RunDate date)
insert into @runtime
values (1, '20150614')
    , (1, '20150914'), (1, '20161004'), (2, '20140501')
    , (2, '20160921'), (3, '20160312'), (3, '20171214')
```

I believe your main issue is consecutive categories with the same value. You need to group such values and find min effective date for each such group. This is what is done in `cte` part. Then just join two tables to get expected output.

```
;with cte as (
    select
        ID, Category, Effective = min(Effective)
        , EndDate = isnull(lead(min(Effective)) over (partition by ID order by min(Effective)), '99991231')
    from (
        select 
            *, grp = row_number() over (partition by ID order by Effective)
            - row_number() over (partition by ID, Category order by Effective)
        from 
            @category
    ) t
    group by ID, Category, grp
)

select
    r.ID
from
    @runtime r
    join cte c on r.ID = c.ID and r.RunDate >= c.Effective and r.RunDate < c.EndDate
where
    c.Category = 'A'
```